# Find ID within an excel cell containing multiples values separated by comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find an ID within an excel cell but this cell contains might contain one or multiples values (separated by comma), I've used the following formula but the problem is that only validates against the first value in the cell ignoring the rest (even ignoring the first one if the cell contains multiple values, due to comma next to it) which return incorrect results where the actual value to look for is an another position rather than the first one.

Current formula --> `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)))`

Hope you can help.
Thanks.

Example tables
[image]
[image]

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B2&"*",A:A,0))`

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B2&"*")>0`.

Comment: Just an observation, both are acceptable.  MATCH is a little quicker than COUNTIF.  It will not be noticeable on small data sets but larger than a few thousand it would be.

Comment: Thanks for your help, both answers did the trick, I was not aware that wildcards can be used when looking for a value within a cell. I'll go for the MATCH as Scott suggested since the volume of information to analyzed is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that seems to work based on your description. [ExcelJet: Cell contains specific text](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text)

[Example Table with Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf7CQ.png)